# How to install dev version of network-manager on Debian?

Tags: apt, raspbian, networkmanager

How do I install a newer, dev version of the `network-manager` version on Debian derived systems? It seems to I have to buy the "kitchen sink" of all unstable packages to get just one. I'm specifically asking for Raspbian, but haven't gotten a response on [RPi SE](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/91538/how-to-install-or-compile-package-a-newer-dev-version-of-network-manager-on-ra).

Comment: Please [edit] your question to include the further information you provided on [Raspberrypi.SE]. You should also delete your question there, otherwise this question is liable to be closed for cross-posting.

Answer (score 1):

Get the latest source via `apt-get source network-manager`, get the related packages with `apt-get build-dep network-manager`, then build the package yourself with `dpkg-buildpackage`. Then you can install the .deb file manually.

Comment: When I try to run `sudo apt-get source network-manager`, I get `Reading package lists... Done. E: You must put some 'source' URIs in your sources.list`

Comment: Then put some source uris in your sources.list.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not really a terminal person :/. I don't know what that means or what sources I have to put in my sources.list.